# If $G$ is a finite, abelian group and $m\mid \lvert G\rvert$. Then there must exist a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with order $m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The question says:

> If $G$ is an abelian group with finite order and $m$ such that $m$ divides the $G$'s order. Then there must  exist a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with order $m$.

I have an idea, but I don't dnow if it is correct. Let's try this answer:

> If $m$ is a prime, so the Cauchy's Theorem guarantee the existence of an element with order $m$, so only take the subgroup generated for this element.
>
> If $m$ isn't a prime, then we can write $m = p_1 \cdots p_n$ where $p_i$ is prime for all $i$. And therefore we have $p_i$ divides the $|G|$, $\forall i = 1, \cdots, n. $  Thus, by the remark done before, we have the existence one $d \in G,$ such that $|d_1|= p_1$. For the same way, we get $d_2, \cdots, d_n.$
> Since $p_i$ is prime for all $i$, we have the $\gcd (p_i, p_j) =1 , \forall i \neq j. $ Thus, the $ | \langle d_1, \cdots, d_n \rangle | =  p_1 \cdots p_n= m.$
> It's done,  $ H =   | \langle d_1, \cdots, d_n \rangle |$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: Do you know the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups? Basically finite abelian groups are products of cyclic groups. In that case, the question boils down to producing subgroups of cyclic groups.

Comment: @daruma i think there's generally a philosophy of not referring to the structure theorem when possible, although that certainly will be a valid proof.

Comment: Yes, I do.  The theorem guarantee that $G = \mathbb{Z} ^r \times  \mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \times \cdots  \mathbb{Z}_{n_2} $. But, I was thinking how I can use that, because if $m $ divides $|G|$, I can't understand in what this implies in relation to the m. Can you help me ? @daruma

Comment: @MaySouza there is a decomposition $G=G_{p_1}\times\cdots\times G_{p_n}$ where $G_{p_i}$ has order which is a power of $p_i$. If $m=p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$ then you need $p_i^{n_i}$ dividing the order of $G_{p_i}$.

Comment: Your attempt fails if $n$ is divisible by the square of a prime. It is enough for squarefree $n$, but for example, you haven't shown the existence of a subgroup of order $4$ when $4$ divides $n$.

Comment: Oh, @kentaS, thanks very much. 
I'm so  grateful.

Comment: Also thanks @ArturoMagidin

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if there are subgroups $A,B\subseteq G$ of coprime orders $m,n$, then $AB\subseteq G$ will have order $mn$. Thus, we can reduce to the case where $m$ is a prime power $p^k$.

Let $G$ be a minimal group such that:

- $p^k$ divides the order of $G$; and
- $G$ has no order $p^k$ subgroups.

We can assume $G$ has order $p^n$ with $n> k$, since otherwise its $p$-primary part $G_p$ will be a smaller group satisfying the conditions, contradicting minimality.

Let $H\subsetneq G$ be a maximal proper subgroup. If $G/H$ has order $>p$, then there exists a subgroup $U\subsetneq G/H$ of order $p$ by Cauchy's theorem. However, groups $H\subseteq I\subseteq G$ and subgroups of $G/H$ correspond 1-1, so this is a contradiction (of $H$'s maximality.)

Thus $H$ must be a subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$. If $n-1=k$ we are done, and if $n-1>k$ we are again done by $G$'s minimality.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, essentially doing (strong) induction on $m$ via its factors. However, I suggest you work only with coprime factors $m=m_1m_2$ with $\gcd(m_1,m_2)=1$. Then you can take the product of the $m_1$-group and the $m_2$-group as your $m$-group. On the other hand you need prime *powers* instead of primes as fundamental step; use Sylow for this.

Comment: I think now I can do it. Thanks.